# App engine subdomain redirects on static files (HTTP 301)

Tags: google-app-engine, redirect

I have a domain (let's say) example.com and I want to serve its content (mainly static files - client side app) from the **naked domain**. I also want to **accept subdomains**, so they will not end in error because of DNS or 404. It is common for users to put www in front of the domain (for whatever reason).

I did set up the custom domains in appengine console, the naked and also the * (wildcard). It shows what DNS records I need to have, so I set them up too... exactly the same, A/AAAA records pointing to appengine IPs and * CNAME to appengine alias (googlehosted).

I have read how it behaves by default on https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/domain?csw=1 and I would like to change it a bit. Now the page is accessible from all the domains example.com, www.example.com, blog.example.com etc.

**What I would like is to redirect all request going to anything else than the naked domain to the naked domain without adding any script handler.**

With Apache and modrewrite the solution is easy, as it has a `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}` and `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]`... but is it possible to do this with **app.yaml**? I couldn't find it at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.

I don't want to redirect in javascript (doesn't work for images, css, etc) and I don't like the idea of script handler for all the files, as it IMHO needs to have some performance penalty.

Comment: That is not possible without a backend handler (python/java/go/php...) but you can star this somewhat related issue though: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=444

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by "What I would like is to redirect all request going to anything else than the naked domain to the naked domain without adding any script handler." Explain in more clear language?

Comment: Do you mean to have the redirect happen without the need to use javascript or server-code to do the redirect?

Comment: Yes, exactly (reasons are in the original post at the end).
app.yaml can be configured to send some headers, but not optionally based on the domain name.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you'd like to have any subdomain redirect to the naked domain? Do you mind posting exactly what you currently have in your DNS zone file and what you have in your `Developers Console > Compute > App Engine > Settings > Custom domains` section?

Comment: It is in the original question. It says A/AAAA records for the naked domain and a CNAME for the wildcard. The settings of DNS are exactly the same as the dev console asks in the customs domains. I have no more domains there, just these two. (I cannot post the table here, it's not aligned.)

Answer (score 0):

So, you seem to want to have any subdomains redirect to your naked domain, without needing to write a handler. While you could use a CNAME wildcard on subdomains in your zone file to direct to "@", the naked domain, this is inadvisable since not every provider supports it. You can read more about this strange edge case in an otherwise very standardized system like DNS [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/44618/is-a-wildcard-cname-dns-record-valid).

While you could use a [dispatch file](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/routing) (python doc, but other languages have similar) to catch subdomain requests and send them to a special, simplified "3xx redirect to naked domain" module, short of hosting a GCE instance frontend running Apache, you won't be able to change the user's address bar with the CNAME method, although they will be directed to the IP addresses (A/AAAA records) specified at the apex level of your zonefile ("naked domain"), unless you implement such a module. Apache rewrite rules send exactly such HTTP 3xx responses which redirect the browser to change its URL and request the specified URL (in this case, your naked domain).